# how to compare values in TempData?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am receiving **TempData** values form my controller. i am print them in view, but when i try to compare any of them it shows *syntax error* until i put **alert** before comparison ...
**error free code version:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
<script>
        var i =  @TempData["count"] 

        alert("value of i is as bellow :" + i);
       if (i == 9)
       {

           $('#book_selection').attr("disabled", "disabled");
           alert("disabled...");
       }
</script>
```

but when i remove **alert** , it shows error on **if** statement . how to fix it ?

here is code produces by html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
<title>
    Peace Quran
</title>

<style>
h1{font:25px arial,sans-serif;}
</style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="outer_div" style="background-color:Gainsboro; position:relative; top:50px; left:50px;height:550px;border-radius:8px; border:groove; width:1240px">

      <div id="header" style="background-color:Khaki    ; position:relative; top:5px; left:5px;height:50px;border-radius:8px; border:groove; width:1225px">
      <h1 style="left:550px; position:relative; top:-7px">Admin Panel</h1>
      </div> <!-- header ends-->

      <div id="lef-container" style="background-color:LightSteelBlue    ; position:absolute; top:65px; left:4px;height:475px;border-radius:8px; border:groove; width:280px">    
          <select id="book_selection" style="position:relative; top:10px; left:5px"> 
          <option id="1">Select Book</option> 
          <option id="2" selected>Quran</option>
          <option id="3">Sahi Bukhari</option>
          <option id="4">Sahi Muslim</option>
          <option id="5">Sahi Termzi</option>
          </select>  <!--Book selection ends -->
          <br />
          <input type="button" id="go" value="Go" style="position:relative; top:425px;left:115px;border-radius:5px" />
      </div> <!--left-container ends -->

      <div id="right-container" style="background-color:LightSteelBlue      ; position:absolute; top:65px; left:294px;height:475px;border-radius:8px; border:groove; width:936px">    

<script>


    alert("value of i is as bellow :" + 9);
    alert("disabled...");

</script>
      </div> <!--right-container ends -->


      </div> <!--outer div ends -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of this line "var i =  @TempData["count"]".

Comment: i have tried it .then error transfers to that position ...

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use such razor markup

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
<script>
    @{
        var i = (int)TempData["count"];
    }

    alert("value of i is as bellow :" + @i);

    @if (i == 9)
    {
        <text>
            $('#book_selection').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            alert("disabled...");
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

And [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) you can find some basic rules of Razor using

Comment: error in Visual Studio, or when you open this page in browser? Intellisense for Razor in Visual studio sometimes display strange errors, but code can be fine. This sample works fine for me, when I open it in browser

Comment: what error does it show? Can you post it here or in original question?

Comment: hm, based on your screenshot your </text> tag isn't closed. So it looks like this </text and it should be closed like </text>

Comment: i have closed <text> tag. now their is no error on browser but it is neither showing alert nor disabling book_selection within <text> tag...

Comment: When I set TempData["count"] = 9; in Controller code, and then open it in browser, then it show to me two alerts, that is fine. Can you post here your html code that produced by that page?

Comment: i have posted code in my post. here is something more  :  http://tinypic.com/r/34pi903/5

Comment: oh, I see. You use string "9" in if block, but "i" is int. So they are not equal. You need to use the same types. If you set 'message' value to string, then you need to compare with "9". If you set it to int type, then you need to compare with 9. In my sample in answer I used int

Answer (score 0):

although there are syntax error(s) , still working fine :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
<script>
    @{
        var i = TempData["message"];
    }

    alert("value of i is as bellow :" + @i);
   if (@i == "9")
    {
    $('#book_selection').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     alert("disabled.!");
    }
</scrip
```